# How to select the data with specific values in the column in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table called products. I have the values like XYZ-PR,PR-XYZ,XPR-YZ,XYPR-Z, XYZ.
Assume I have PR is common in that column for most of the values. Now I need to pick the data based on PR
irrespective of the position of PR.
Lets say in this example now I want to retrieve these records. XYZ-PR,PR-XYZ,XPR-YZ,XYPR-Z

Please let me know what is the function we have to use it here in Snowflakae,

Answer (score 1):

You would use `LIKE`:

```
where col like '%PR%
```

Comment: Couple of examples listed here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like.html#examples